# Reduce frequency of deployments in a Java web application using Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, service-layer

Is there a simple way to have your "Service Layer" deployed separately from your web layer, so that I can reduce the number of times per week that I have to, package, build and deploy the entire WAR file?

I'm using Tomcat mostly, but I'm hoping for something more generic to Java web servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the package-build-deploy process is necessary, but heavyweight enough that you want to minimize or avoid it, you might also consider making that process easier, faster, or more automated.

Answer (score 2):

You could move your "service layer" to a second application and have the front-end application communicate with the "services" using some sort of remoting technology.

[Spring Remoting (a.k.a. HttpInvoker)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-httpinvoker) makes this very simple to use.

Comment: I've used this before, and it seems to work pretty well, however, I don't want the services to be remote, because it's possible that some of the services I'm talking about (Marty Fowler services) are plain Java code and I don't want to lose performance to use them